# Target Display Mode -- Pressing command-F2 does nothing

Tags: target-display

I would like to avail myself of the target display mode.  I have a brand new MacBook Pro Retnia, and I'd like to use it as a display for my Mac Pro (also brand new).  I followed the instructions on [this page](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH19038?locale=en_US), and nothing happened when I pressed command F2.  Then I started scouring the forums.  I found several threads with the same problem, and I tried all the suggestions.  I checked my preferences to see if the keyboard assignments were messed up.  I tried restarting both computers in various orders.  I tried using internal and external keyboards on both computers.  I tried adding the fn key to the key command.  I spent a couple hours on this, but sadly, nothing worked.

So I'm really hoping that someone here has some idea what's going on.  This experience has really been disheartening.  I just bought these computers this year, and they failed at something so basic.  At this point, I would be satisfied just to see an error message telling me why cmd-F2 doesn't work.  I mean, if I try to eject a disk that has files that are currently in use, it will tell me why it can't eject right now.  But with this, I'm completely in the dark.  It's so frustrating!

Comment: Did you try Fn/Cmd/F2 ? By default the Function keys are set to be 'media' keys not F-Keys. Fn swaps their 'function'.

Comment: Hmmm… [Apple KB](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592) appears to say only iMacs can do it

Answer (score 1):

iMac 27 5K Late 2014 model and later no longer support Target Display Mode.

Comment: While correct, this doesn't really help the OP (who is using an MBP). On the other hand, the MBP never supported Target Display Mode anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that Target Display Mode will work, but only if I do command-f2 from the **login screen**. After logging in, the command does nothing.

Hope this helps someone! Running 2011 27-inch iMac as display with MacBook Air and a thunderbolt cable on El Capitan.

Answer (score 1):

The MacBook Pro does not support target display mode. Only iMacs (not-5k) do.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue, it worked by connecting the keyboard that originally came with the imac and then using Command + F1. This worked the first time. Second time onwards Command + F2 worked.